# WPF bubble messages like in the iphone sms

Tags: wpf

Can you refer me to an WPF implementation of a "sms chat bubbles" where I can feed texts in different colors for questions and answers (like in the iphone sms application) :

http://www.mobilelove.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/iPhone_sms_Bubble_style_by_alexandergre.jpg

If you can think of other nice solution, I'm interested as well

Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 3):

Typically that style of button is called a **Glass(y) Button** or a **Gloss(y) Button**. I won't insult you by posting the first few Google results from searching for those terms, but that's where you can begin to look.

Comment: I am a WPF begginer! And I do merge the knowledge of google + people like you here on SO, to go on. Your first part of the answer was enlighting and despite the fact that it is not what I am after, I bet that one day I will. Therefor I thank you for that. The answer could feel great if you had stopped there. Still I do thank you